# Shell shift procedure - What is this?

Tags: linux, shell, shift

In shell we have the command shift, but i saw on some example its giving shift 3

Why there is a number after shift ? and what its about ? what it does ?

Example:

```
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3”
shift
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3”
shift   
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3”
shift  
echo “arg1= $1  arg2=$2 arg3=$3”
shift
```

The output will be:

```
arg1= 1 arg2=2  arg3=3 
arg1= 2 arg2=3  arg3= 
arg1= 3 arg2=   arg3=
arg1=   arg2=   arg3=
```

But when i add that, it doesn't display it correctly.

Comment: See answers below.  `shift 3` is essentially the same as `shift; shift; shift`.

Answer (score 49):

Take a look at the [man](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) page, which says:

```
shift [n]
    The  positional parameters from n+1 ... are renamed to $1 .... 
    If n is not given, it is assumed to be 1.
```

An Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Input: $@"
shift 3
echo "After shift: $@"
```

Run it:

```
$ myscript.sh one two three four five six

Input: one two three four five six
After shift: four five six
```

This shows that after shifting by 3, `$1=four`, `$2=five` and `$3=six`.

Answer (score 2):

you use `man bash` to find the `shift` builtin command:

> shift [n]
>
> The positional parameters from n+1 ... are renamed  to  $1  ....
>   Parameters  represented  by  the  numbers  $# down to $#-n+1 are
>   unset.  n must be a non-negative number less than  or  equal  to
>   $#.   If  n is 0, no parameters are changed.  If n is not given,
>   it is assumed to be 1.  If n is greater than $#, the  positional
>   parameters  are  not changed.  The return status is greater than
>   zero if n is greater than $# or less than zero; otherwise 0.

Answer (score 1):

This would be answered simply by reading either the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-shift-121), or typing `man shift`:

> ```
>       shift [n]
> ```
>
> Shift the positional parameters to the left by n. The positional
>   parameters from n+1 ... $# are renamed to $1 ... $#-n. Parameters
>   represented by the numbers $# to $#-n+1 are unset. n must be a
>   non-negative number less than or equal to $#. If n is zero or greater
>   than $#, the positional parameters are not changed. If n is not
>   supplied, it is assumed to be 1. The return status is zero unless n is
>   greater than $# or less than zero, non-zero otherwise.

Comment: Not sure why, but I have no manual entry for shift. Maybe it depends on the distro, but the bash manual does have it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Shift the positional parameters to the left by n. The positional parameters from n+1 ... $# are renamed to $1 ... $#-n. Parameters represented by the numbers $# to $#-n+1 are unset. n must be a non-negative number less than or equal to $#. If n is zero or greater than $#, the positional parameters are not changed. If n is not supplied, it is assumed to be 1. The return status is zero unless n is greater than $# or less than zero, non-zero otherwise.

1. List item

Answer (score 0):

`shift` treat command line arguments as a FIFO queue, 
it popleft element every time it's invoked.

```
array = [a, b, c]
shift equivalent to
array.popleft
[b, c]
$1, $2,$3 can be interpreted as index of the array.
```

[bash - The advantage of shift over reassign value straightforward - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49777598/the-advantage-of-shift-over-reassign-value-straightforward)