# Averaging lines without awk using bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm just starting to use bash, and I'm having some difficulties with bash arithmetic. Lets say I have a some cities with three temperatures, and I'd like to average the temperatures without using the awk command. How can I do this? I've done it with awk, but I'm practicing with different techniques.

```
# cityTemp.txt with four cities, three day's temperatures
Toronto 20 25 30
Miami 80 80 110
London 40 20 60
New York 5 10 15
```

Lets say I'm trying to write a script to output:

```
25 Toronto
90 Miami
40 London
10 New York
```

I've already done this with some piping and the awk command, but I'm having problems doing this without using awk.

Again, I'm new to this. I tried a for loop, but I didn't really know what I was doing.

---edit 1:

Benjamin W. I'm editing again, but right now I'm playing with a loop:

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(cat $1)
do
    echo "i is: ${i}"
done < $1
```

This is, maybe obviously, just printing every field from cityTemp.txt one at a time.

---edit 2:

This was my ending attempt

```
while read -a rows
do
    total=0
    sum=0
    for i in "${rows[@]}"
    do
        sum=`expr $sum + $i`
        total=`expr $total + 1`
    done
    average=`expr $sum / $total`
    Output = ${average}
done < $1
echo ${averages}
```

Comment: What does your for loop look like? How did it not work? You can [edit] your question to add some information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I've had a few things going, but nothing was quite working. This is where I am again. I was trying to use expr() before, but it was hard for me to only view columns 2,3,4

Comment: will the temp always be 3 values or do you need something to work with an arbitrary number of tempreatures

Comment: I've only been working with 3 values, but varying numbers of cities (always formatted:city temp temp temp), though if you could apply range I'd of course like to learn. --edit-- I did put a zip code in there that I put in brackets, but I only got that all to work with awk

Comment: Your final version relies on the fact that a string is evaluated as zero in an arithmetic context, as you're treating all the city names as a numbers; cf. `i=York; echo $(( i + 1 ))`. It works, but I'm not sure if you were aware of this happening.

Comment: Oh, and instead of editing your question to basically add an answer, you can also add it as a proper, separate answer.

Comment: You cannot have whitespace around the equals sign in an assignment.  http://shellcheck.net/ is your friend.

Comment: Thank you, the white space has been throwing me off with bash scripts. Didn't know I had to pay this much attention to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work in any Posix shell, so we may as well [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) it with `#!/bin/sh.`

```
#!/bin/sh

avg () {
  city=
  while [ $# -gt 3 ]; do
    city="$city $1"
    shift
  done
  echo $((($1 + $2 + $3) / 3)) $city
}

while read line; do
  avg $line
done < cityTemp.txt
```

This would have been a lot easier if the city was last on each line, lol.

Comment: Yes, see `test(1)` which is aliased to `[` **. . .** I'm accumulating words so that cities with spaces in their names work.

Comment: Oh man, thank you. Just so I know whats going on, the avg() is you creating a function in this scope? Then you're calling it and passing it a line

Comment: Yes.  By putting most of the code in the shell function I could use the `shift` operator.

Comment: Ah, I get it now! Neat.

Comment: I assume the shift procedure being the one outlined [in this forum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10414391/shell-shift-procedure-what-is-this)

Answer (score 0):

this should work for a file with an arbitrary nymber of lines and 3 teampreature inputs:

```
#!/bin/bash
i=1
file=file
nolines=`wc -l $file | cut -d' ' -f1`
while [ $i -lt $nolines ]
do
line=$(sed -n "$i"p $file)
city=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f1)
val1=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f2)
val2=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f3)
val3=$(echo $line | cut -d' ' -f4)
sum=$(($val1 + $val2 + $val3))
avg=$(($sum / 3))
echo $avg $city
i=$[i+1]
done
```

Answer (score 0):

This takes advantage of a few Bash features, but ended up rather bulky:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                                                                         

# Regex to capture city name and temperatures                                                                                       
re='([[:alpha:] ]*) ([[:digit:] ]*)'                                                                                                

while IFS= read -r line; do                                                                                                         
    unset temps                             # Delete array                                                                                                  
    [[ $line =~ $re ]]                      # Capture city name and temperatures
    city="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"               # Assign city name                                                                              
    read -a temps <<< "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"  # Assign temperatures to array                                                          

    sum=0                                                                                                                           

    # Loop over temperatures                                                                                                        
    for temp in "${temps[@]}"; do                                                                                                   
        (( sum += temp ))                                                                                                           
    done                                                                                                                            

    # Print average                                                                                                                 
    printf "%d %s\n" $(( sum / ${#temps[@]} )) "$city"                                                                              
done < "$1"
```

It would be much simpler if the city name always consisted of the same amount of words, but there is "New York", so I use a regex to separate name and temperatures.

The temperatures are then assigned to an array with `read -a`, over which I loop to get the total.

Assigning to the array to loop over could be replaced by directly looping over the string and relying on word splitting:

```
for temp in ${BASH_REMATCH[2]}; do
```

but then we'd have to keep track of the number of temperature values by updating a counter or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version that uses Bash's builtin regex to add the arbitrary elements after the city names.

Given:

```
$ echo "$nums"
Toronto 20 25 30
Miami 80 80 110
London 40 20 60
New York 5 10 15
```

You can do:

```
regex="^([a-zA-Z ]+)(.+)$"
echo "$nums" | while read line
do
    [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
    name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    arr=(${BASH_REMATCH[2]})
    sum=0
    for i in ${arr[@]}; do
        let sum+=$i
    done
    printf "%s %s\n" $(( $sum / ${#arr[@]} )) "$name"
done
```

Prints:

```
25 Toronto 
90 Miami 
40 London 
10 New York
```

If you want floating point, you can use `bc` like so.

Given:

```
$ echo "$nums"
Toronto 22 25 30
Miami 80 80 110
London 40 20 60
New York 5 10 15
```

You can do:

```
echo "$nums" | while read line
do
    [[ $line =~ $regex ]]
    name="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
    arr=(${BASH_REMATCH[2]})
    avg=$(IFS='+'; echo "scale=2;(${arr[*]})/${#arr[@]}" | bc -l)
    printf "%s %s\n" $avg "$name"   
done
```

Prints:

```
25.66 Toronto 
90.00 Miami 
40.00 London 
10.00 New York
```