# The advantage of shift in shell script over reassign value straightforward

Tags: bash

I don't understand the `shift` in following code:

```
    #! /usr/local/bin/bash
    # process command line options
    interactive=
    filename=
    while [[ -n $1 ]]; do
        case $1 in 
            -f | --file)    shift #don't understand the shift #No.1
                            filename=$1 ;;
            -i | --interactive) interactive=1
                                ;;
            -h | --help)    usage
                            exit;;
            *)              echo "usage >&2 exit 1";;
        esac
        shift # don't understand the shift #2
    done

    #interactive mode
    if [[ -n $interactive ]]; then
       echo "do something"
    fi
    #output html page
    if [[ -n $filename ]]; then
        if touch $filename && [[ -f $filename ]]; then
           echo "write_html_page > $filename" #debug 
        else
            echo "$program: Cannot write file $filename " >&2
            exit 1
        fi
    else
        echo "write_html_page to terminal" # debug
    fi
```

Test it

```
    $ bash question.sh -f test
    write_html_page > test

    $ bash question.sh -f
    write_html_page to terminal
```

When I delete `shift` and change `filename=$1` to `filename=$2`

```
    $ bash question.sh -f
    write_html_page to terminal
  # it works properly

    $ bash question.sh -f test
    usage >&2 exit 1
    write_html_page > test 
  # it almost function  nicely except that `usage >&2 exit 1` is executed.
```

So the `shift` cannot be replaced by `filename=$2` entirely.

The second shift at the botton if deleted, the loop run endlessly.

Could I interpret `shift` intuitively?
I did't find such a magic command in other languages.

Comment: `shift` allows the code above to parse the command line in a loop without caring about the order of the options (`-f`, `-i`, `-h` etc). Using `shift`, the loop consumes one (or two) command line parameters on each iteration (the parameters that were already interpreted).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`shift` will remove the first positional argument, and shift every other argument left one.

For example, let's consider the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
shift
echo "$@"
shift
echo "$@"
```

Given that `echo "$@"` will print all of the arguments, if you were to run this, then the following would happen:

```
./test.bash 1 2 3 4 5

echo "$@"  # prints 1 2 3 4 5
shift      # Removes 1 and shifts everything else along
echo "$@"  # prints 2 3 4 5
shift      # shifting again
echo "$@"  # prints 3 4 5
```

In your example, the script is parsing all of the flags. `-i` and `-h` are just switches and handle no following arguments. However, `-f` requires a `filename`.

The second `shift` will process the flag, shift the arguments, and then process them again. Therefore you can have `./program.bash -i -f filename`. The `-i` will be shifted by the second shift, and then the filename will be processed on the next loop.

If you were to run `./program.bash -f filename -i`, then the `filename` would need to be shifted along with the `-f`. Therefore, on the case block for `-f` there is an extra shift. In this example, `-f` would be shifted inside the case block, and then `filename` would be shifted by the second `shift`. Then the loop would run again to process any further flags.

As the while loop is `[[ -n $1 ]]`, the loop will run until there are no more arguments.

Comment: Does the `shift` within `case` not effect the value on `while [[ -n $1 ]]`.

Comment: ` -f | --file)    shift` this shift change the value of `while [[ -n $1 ]]`, ty, I got your ideas. It's like popleft a array.

Comment: Yes - just like a popleft array. but you need to pop twice with `-f`. Given that the second shift pops on every iteration, we just need to pop one more time for `-f` thus why the first shift is required also.

Answer (score 2):

The example on this page:

> http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html

explains what it's doing.

EDIT:

The example:

> A shift statement is typically used when the number of arguments to a command is not known in advance, for instance when users can give as many arguments as they like. In such cases, the arguments are usually processed in a while loop with a test condition of (( $# )). This condition is true as long as the number of arguments is greater than zero. The $1 variable and the shift statement process each argument. The number of arguments is reduced each time shift is executed and eventually becomes zero, upon which the while loop exits.

Comment: Can you ad the relevant parts here? When your link goes stale, the answer becomes useless.

Comment: @Robert Added it now.